# iPhone SDK, passing strings through views

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I'm trying to pass a string through two views on an iPhone app. On my second view that I want to recover the string in the .h i have:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MBProgressHUD.h"
#import "RootViewController.h"

@interface PromotionViewController : UITableViewController {

    NSString *currentCat;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *currentCat;

@end
```

And in the .m i have:

```
@synthesize currentCat;
```

However, in the first view controller when I try and set that variable I get a not found error:

```
PromotionViewController *loadXML = [[PromotionViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PromotionViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:loadXML animated:YES];
        [PromotionViewController currentCat: @"Test"];
```

That third line gives me a: Class method +currentCat not found

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tom,
The issue in your code appears that you are trying to set the string using a static method call to the class. This would work if you implemented a static method named currentCat:

I don't think this is what your want.
See below on how to correct your issue.

```
[PromotionViewController currentCat:@"Test"];
//This will not work as it is calling the class itself not an instance of it.

[loadXml setCurrentCat:@"Test"];
//This will work. Keep in mind if you are going to call the objective-c 
//synthesize setting directly you will need to capitalize the first letter 
//of your instance variable name and add "set" to the front as I've done.

//Alternatively in objective-c 2.0 you can also use 
//the setter method with the . notation

loadXml.currentCat = @"Test";
//This will work too
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the string like this, as it's a property and not a method:

```
NSString* myString = controller.currentCat; // where controller is an instance of PromotionViewController
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do:

```
loadXML.currentCat = @"Test";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
PromotionViewController *loadXML = [[PromotionViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PromotionViewController" bundle:nil];
[loadXML setCurrentCat: @"Test"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:loadXML animated:YES];
```

That should do it.